# Selecting character (:) where it is not between two expressions

Tags: regex

I am facing a small problem where I can not select the character ':' which are not between two digits before and after ':' . Here are the examples:

```
user1:18 (should match)
date:2018-06-28 16:12:09 (should match : after 'date')
dueDate:28 (should match)
details:none (should match)
```

In the demo I only got look for the two digits foward. Someone can help me, please?

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3sdvg)

Comment: No, sorry. I wrote wrong

Comment: What language/tool/library are you using?

Comment: I am writing a script for logstash. I am parsing strings and I need solve this problem :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with logstash. Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: Sure... I am using the gsub function https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.3/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub

Although I am using logstash, my problem is just with the regex expression, so there's no need no go deep in this topic

Comment: OK, that documentation sucks. It says nothing about the supported regex format or how the replacement string works. The source seems to be at https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-mutate/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/mutate.rb, which looks like Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logically appropriate regex for this is

```
(?<!\d):|:(?!\d)
```

I.e. a `:` not preceded by a digit or a `:` not followed by a digit (which matches all `:` except those surrounded by digits on both sides).

It looks like `gsub` from `mutate` just calls Ruby's native `gsub`, which supports both look-ahead and look-behind (`(?! )` and `(?<! )`, respectively).

Answer (score 2):

`/:[^\d]|[^\d]:/` matches any colon that is either preceded by a non-digit or followed by a non-digit.  Is that good enough?

Comment: Probably not if this is a replacement operation. Also, it doesn't handle `::` correctly.

Comment: No because it must be an AND operation and select only ':'

Comment: @RodolphoGheleri, instead of p AND q, the answer provides ~p OR ~q which are equivalent.

Comment: @gaganso You are correct. Thanks for highlight that

Comment: It is not *exactly* the same -- it wouldn't match ":" alone, for example, but it could be tweaked to do so.

Answer (score 1):

`/:(?=[^\d])|(?<=[^\d]):/`

Using assertions, you can avoid consuming characters for the purpose of assertion.

Comment: Your parens look broken.

Comment: Thank you, @melpomene! This handles `::`. Do you see any other issues?

Comment: This doesn't match a string containing just `:`.

Comment: Thanks for help :)